# Can I change where "cd <enter>" takes me?

Tags: command-line

Specifically I'm wondering if, while working on a project, if I do `cd` it can take me to the root of the project and if I'm anywhere else then I get the default behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"?
I the following alias for mercurial projects:
alias cdroot='cd $(hg root)'

Comment: You can use pushd instead of cd when you first leave the project root, then use popd to return when you're ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function projectcd() {
  arg="$1"
  if [[ ! -z $arg ]] ; then
    cd $arg
  elif [[ $(pwd) == /home/user/project/root/* ]] ; then
    cd /home/user/project/root/
  else
    cd
  fi
}
alias cd=projectcd
```

Comment: You could simplify this a bit and avoid the `alias` by just calling the function `cd`. If you do so, you can refer to the built in `cd` as `builtin cd`. And you'll have to in the function definition.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Where I was headed was to make projectcd take two parameters.  $1 would be the project root directory and $2 the optional argument from cd.  Then the alias would set the project root directory (and could be changed easily) without needing to modify the function.  Nevertheless, as written, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CDPATH` to define the base directory for `cd` command

```
[ramesh@dev-db ~]# pwd
/home/ramesh

[ramesh@dev-db ~]# cd mail
-bash: cd: mail: No such file or directory
[Note: This is looking for mail directory under current directory]

[ramesh@dev-db ~]# export CDPATH=/etc
[ramesh@dev-db ~]# cd mail
[Note: This is looking for mail under /etc and not under current directory]

[ramesh@dev-db /etc/mail]# pwd
/etc/mail
```

Comment: That's cool, but if i do just cd it still sends me to the home directory

Comment: @geermc4 You can change your `HOME` env var.